# AttributeError when running a Github code for 9 Men Morris Game

Tags: python

I am trying to play around with the NineMenMorris code below on GitHub but when I run it I get the error below.

The error comes up after getting a Morris (3 in a row) and the algorithm asks to select an opponent figure to eat.

https://github.com/boris-ns/NineMensMorris

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-47e27bb9316e> in <module>
      6     player2 = Human('B', game)
      7     game.set_players(player1, player2)
----> 8     game.place_figures_phase1()

<ipython-input-3-8aed7b0be5a0> in place_figures_phase1(self)
    287                 white_position = self._player1.place_figure()
    288                 self.place_figure_on_table(self._player1.mark, white_position)
--> 289                 self._while_closed_morris(white_position)
    290             else:              # Black on the move
    291                 black_position = self._player2.place_figure()

<ipython-input-3-8aed7b0be5a0> in _while_closed_morris(self, pozicija)
    261         if self.check_if_closed_morris(self._player1.mark, pozicija):
    262             self.draw_table()
--> 263             position_eat = self._player1.eat_opponents_figure()
    264             if position_eat == -1:
    265                 return

<ipython-input-1-1cfba64f88fc> in eat_opponents_figure(self)
     81                 continue
     82 
---> 83             if self.game_instance.eat_figure(self.mark, position):
     84                 return position
     85 

<ipython-input-3-8aed7b0be5a0> in eat_figure(self, mark, position)
    206             return False
    207 
--> 208         if mark == self._player1.oznaka:
    209             if self.check_if_closed_morris(self._player2.oznaka, position):
    210                 return False

AttributeError: 'Human' object has no attribute 'oznaka'
```

Comment: try replacing `self._player1.ozanka`, with `self._player1.mark`. look like the code was translated recently and he might have missed replacing that

Comment: I did and now I get a new error AttributeError: 'Human' object has no attribute 'broj_figura'. How did you figure out it was .mark?

Comment: I changed "self._player1.broj_figura" to "self._player1.num_of_figures" which seems to have solved that but now the error is "AttributeError: 'Human' object has no attribute 'oznaka'"... it might possibly be a language issue

Comment: the person change ozanka to mark in other places, he might have just forgot to do it there :). Replace all places where there is ozanka with mark :)

Comment: fixed all the language issues and now getting a new error! `AttributeError: 'Ai' object has no attribute 'eat_opponents_figure'`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions.

@KetZoomer solved it

> try replacing `self._player1.ozanka`, with `self._player1.mark`. look like
> the code was translated recently and he might have missed replacing
> that

few other errors include;

- `self._player1.broj_figura` to `self._player1.num_of_figures`
- position